# Python IO: disable standard output stream and print what we want

Tags: python, io, output, outputstream

Say I have a python program composed of three lines.

```
if __name__=“__main__”:
   foo( )
   print “Hello”
```

Here, `foo( )` is a  third-part function that outputs things to the standard output. E.g, `foo( )` has only one line `print 'I am here'`. The point is that I have no permission to change **foo()** which may contain output  statements, and I don't want to mix its output with mine.

**Question**:

How can I change  the third line of the program above (print “Hello”), so that this program

1.only prints “Hello”, and

2.does not print anything from `foo( )`?

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: If you want to access the value later you can store it in a StringIO object http://pastebin.com/NHWAjJQv

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It is good to know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redirect `stdout` to `os.devnull` (the null device); the following:

```
import os
import sys
def foo():
  print "foo"
if __name__ == "__main__":
  out = sys.stdout
  null = open(os.devnull, 'w')
  sys.stdout = null
  foo()
  sys.stdout = out
  print "Hello"
```

will print `Hello`. You can read about the null device [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device#Usage).

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response. I have been looking for something like >/dev/null.

Comment: No need to thank me - rather accept my question, I don't mind the reputation ;P